# retrieve value on post api call - terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I have been trying to write a code using terraform which must do an API call on POST and it must get back value on post, this return value on post I must be able to use it else where in the code.

Reading a lot I noticed there are two ways to do it

1. Mastercard Rest API
2. Local-Exec and Null provider

The first one also has some issues when we try to fetch a value on post, unfortunately the API I am trying to call needs some input values to return an output. If anyone has experience in doing this using the mastercard rest api please let me know how.

My curl statement looks like this -

```
curl --insecure -X POST 'https://url.fqdn/get_hostname' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic tokenvalue' -d '{"key": "value","key": "value","key": "value"}'
```

Using local-exec and null provider

```
resource "null_resource" "get-hostname" {
provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = <<EOF
    curl --insecure -X POST 'https://url.fqdn/get_hostname' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic tokenvalue' -d '{"key1": "value1","key2": "value2"}'
    EOF
}
```

}

How can I get the output of the command property ?

Comment: if you get back a json answer from the api call, you could use terraform external data source and write an script using jq to parse the json

Comment: or use `jsondecode()` to natively parse it in TF

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect the output of curl to a file, and process that file within another null_resource block with an explicit dependency on the one that writes the file.

Comment: I was also thinking of the same, but I am unsure how to handle this scenario with the file when there are many parallel executions. What would be the unique file that should be called by every provisioning module , then I thought to use rand provider to generate different file names.

Comment: Actually, c4f4t0r's suggestion wouldn't require an output file since curl can output clean json, see https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source